# Java BufferedReader frozen

Tags: java, networking

So I am trying to basically do this -
1. I send a TCP packet that contains a string "ping".
2. I receive the response "pong".

This is my client code:
(Its not supposed to be used in production, just using it as a test platform basically)

```java
        int f =0;
        System.out.println(f++);
        Socket socket = new Socket("root.aaronakhtar.me", 4000);
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        System.out.println(f++);
        writer.write("ping");
        System.out.println(f++);
        writer.flush();
        System.out.println(f++);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println(f++);
        if (line != null){
            System.out.println(line);
        }else{
            System.out.println("null");
        }
        System.out.println(f++);
        writer.close();
        reader.close();
        socket.close();
        System.out.println(f++);
```

When I run the client it outputs as following:

```
0
1
2
3
```

but does not do anything while its on 3 (BufferedReader).

This is the server:

```java
                while (true) {
                    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    String line = reader.readLine();
                    if (line != null) {
                        objectOutputStream.writeBytes(check(line));
                        objectOutputStream.flush();
                    }
                    objectOutputStream.close();
                    reader.close();
                    socket.close();
                    System.out.println("ping");
                }
```

it never outputs "ping"...

check() method:

```java
    private String check(String input){
        switch (input.toLowerCase()){

            case "ping":{ //used for simple network checks
                return "pong";
            }




        }
        return "null"; // returns "null" if the input does not match.
    }
```

I have been stuck on this for a while now, I have researched and asked others but no one has seemed to have found a valid solution.

Comment: Do `writer.println("ping")`, because you are doing a `reader.readLine()` on the server side.

Comment: You are reading lines but you aren't writing lines.